# What does this variable mean inside of lambda argument?

Tags: android, kotlin

Unfamiliar variable on code

Searched for lambda excplanation

```
fun clickTimePicker(view: View) {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR)
        val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

        val tpd = TimePickerDialog(this,TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(function = {
        view, h, m -> Toast.makeText(this, h.toString() + " : " + m +" : " , 

        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }),hour,minute,false)

        tpd.show()
    }
```

1.what does h and m in that variable mean?

2.what does `function =` do ?

3.why `view` is not used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the `hourOfDay` and `minute` values as seen in [the documentation for `OnTimeSetListener` and its `onTimeSet()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener.html#onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker,%20int,%20int)).

Your lambda expression forms the body of `onTimeSet()`, and the three lambda parameters are the three parameters for `onTimeSet()`.

**UPDATE**: regarding the two additional questions that you added later:

- `function =` is not needed there. My guess is that for Kotlin SAM conversions, `function` is the name given for the lambda that will be converted into the interface's function.
- As to why `view` is unused, they did not need it to show the `Toast`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [official documentation] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener), it refers to the hour Of Day and minute.

```
view- TimePicker: the view associated with this listener
h   - int: the hour that was set
m   - int: the minute that was set
```